# Forward main domain but not subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, subdomain

I'm looking to forward `www.example.com` to `www.otherexample.com` while keeping `sub.example.com` intact (it points to a tumblr blog right now). I've been digging around for a way to do this through DNS, but is `.htaccess` my best bet here? If so, what should I include in the file? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: some clarification here, sub.example.com points to a tumblr blog through an A-record change.

Answer (score 3):

You could use CNAME DNS resource record for www.example.com, eg.

```
www IN CNAME www.otherexample.com.
```

Comment: I set this through my hosting service (awardspace) a few days ago now, and for some reason it doesn't seem to work. Thoughts?